# Latex tool for Feynman diagrams

Tags: resource-recommendations, feynman-diagrams, software

Is there a tool for drawing Feynman diagrams that can be used to post these diagrams on physics stack exchange?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's about software and not physics.

Comment: Actually, upon reading it a second time (more closely), this really should be asked on [meta]

Comment: The reason I ask is that I want to ask questions about feynman diagrams on physics stack exchange

Comment: yes, and I don't think it's an enabled package in MathJax. Most times I see the diagrams, it's a screenshot.

Comment: I would say it should be moved to TexSE they might have the answer, but just so you know there are Tex packages like feynmp that do this for you. I personally use jaxodraw to make images then use them later.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate and I'm voting to reopen. "Which LaTeX package do you use for Feynman diagrams" is a much more specific question than "what software do you use in general for all diagrams".

Comment: [I use Tikz](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10548/84967).

Comment: @knzhou even reading it as "what software to use", this is clearly off-topic. But reading it as written, this should clearly be migrated to [meta] instead, as it's about the capabilities of this site.

Comment: I also think it belongs in Meta, so I'm voting to reopen.